# Where can i get the windows phone sdk for visual studio express 2013?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-express

I want to make a windows phone 8 app using visual studio express 2013. Do I need to get an sdk? is it built in? Do I have to upgrade to ultimate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to install [Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff630878%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

You cannot get the same Visual Studio integration and templates without specifically installing the phone support when installing a full edition of Visual Studio 2013.

Note that Windows Phone 8 development tools require Windows 8 or higher as Hyper-V is required for the Windows Phone 8 emulator.

There is an add-in available to extend existing installations, but it won't work for the 2013 Express edition.

You can also [install the SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471), but you'll need to use Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Phone for development. You'll not be able to use Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Either visit http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk or Go to Visual studio File->new->Project->Visual C#->Windows Phone then It will ask to install windows phone SDK

Answer (score 0):

You need the Windows Phone SDK 8.0!
http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk